How can I allocate multiple arrays of different types in a single allocation?
I am coding a probing hash set which internally maintains an array of slots as well as a separate array of slot metadata:
template <typename T, typename Hasher = std::hash<T>, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class HashSet {
    T *slots;              // Array of slots
    uint8_t *metadata;     // Array of metadata (each slot has a single byte of metadata)
    Allocator allocator;
    /* ... */
}

Now, in my current implementation, the slots and metadata arrays use separate allocations. In particular, I use placement new/delete for slots (via std::allocator_traits) to avoid unnecessarily invoking T's default constructor. For metadata, however, I have just been using regular new[]/delete[], because the metadata always needs to be initialized at the start anyways. Thus, my code looks as follows (using my reserve function as an example):
// Inside `class HashSet`
void reserve(size_t new_capacity) {
    if (curr_capacity >= new_capacity) return;

    // Allocate new slots and metadata arrays separately
    auto new_slots = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator, new_capacity);
    auto new_metadata = new uint8_t[new_capacity];

    /* Rehash all elements, and move them to `new_slots`... */

    // Deallocate the old `slots` and `metadata` arrays
    if (slots) std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(allocator, slots, curr_capacity);
    delete[] metadata;

    /* Set `slots` and `metadata` to `new_slots` and `new_metadata`, and update `curr_capacity`... */
}

Now, I've realized that allocating both arrays in a single allocation would improve locality of reference. However, I am unsure of how to do this. In particular, I'm pretty sure that simply allocating a large char* buffer and treating it as the elements array concatenated to the metadata array would violate memory alignment rules. At the same time, I'm worried about the fact that I use different strategies for managing the slots and the metadata (placement new/delete vs regular new/delete); I have been considering just using placement new/delete for everything.
Overall, my question is: How can I create two differently-typed arrays in a single contiguous allocation, for the purposes of improving cache locality?
The only thing I know of which is similar to this is the fact that std::make_shared allocates both the value as well as the reference counter in a single allocation. However, I don't know how that is achieved.

Suggestion: Allocator is an empty class, so you can eliminate the space it occupies through [[no_unique_address]].

You could define a struct that holds 1 T and 1 uint8_t, and then allocate 1 array with that struct as its element type.
Otherwise, you'll have to allocate a single char[] buffer that is large enough to hold both arrays and alignment padding between them, and then use placement-new to create the uint8_t elements in part of the memory, and the T elements in the remaining memory.

Could you add some details on how large the single char[] buffer would need to be to satisfy alignment? I know that if I have a capacity of C, I would need at least C + sizeof(T) * C bytes just to hold all the metadata and all the values, but how much more would I need for alignment?

@ChristopherMiller if you put the metadata values before the T values, then simply round up the 1st C to the next even multiple of alignof(T). Otherwise, put the metadata values after the T values

Could you confirm why to round the 1st C up to the next even multiple of alignof(T), rather than just any multiple of alignof(T)? I've always thought that alignment was just a constraint that the starting memory address be any multiple of that alignment.

uint8_t probably doesn't need any special alignment, so you can safely placement new it at any address. If in doubt, use unsigned char instead.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, but there's no such guarantee for T, so its alignment does need to be accounted for

Normal dynamic allocation functions return addresses aligned for any type, so it is safe to place an array of anything at the beginning

@n.m.couldbeanAI  you dont seem to be getting my point. Imagine C is not an even multiple of alignof(T). Let's just say 3 and 4, respectively. If the metadata values were placed  before the T values in a char[] buffer, then 4-3=1 padding byte is needed after the metadata values to ensure the 1st T value is aligned properly.

"If the metadata values were placed before the T" So don't do that.

Or if you really need to do that, pad the metadata to a multiple of sizeof(T) (or alignof(T)) bytes, why is this a problem?

@n.m.couldbeanAI it is not a problem. You are just repeating what I already suggested earlier.

@RemyLebeau I'm sorry, I meant to comment the main question, not your answer! My fault.
